# Cross-walking zip codes to municipalities

Tags: r, sf

I would like to crosswalk German zipcodes to municipalities.
Unfortunately, zipcodes are not unique - at least according to the data
I have access to, a zipcode can be associated with multiple
municipalities/counties. For example, a zipcode
[22929](https://www.suche-postleitzahl.org/plz-gebiet/22929) is
associated with a couple of municipalities (towns).

So far, I have tried to match zipcodes with municipalities with
`st_join(zips, municips, largest = TRUE)`. Since the zipcode geometry
object is a multi-polygon, casting them into polygons helped in some
cases. In the case of the example zipcode (22929), it’s possible to
match three of its polygons to three municipalities with the above line
of code (`st_cast`ing + `st_join`). However, since the other two
polygons are connected with each other, it’s not straightforward to
match to two municipalities. If we look at the zipcode data, i.e., the
column `note`, we see that this zipcode is associated with five
municipalities: Hamfelde, Kasseburg, Köthel, Rausdorf, and Schönberg.

---

```r
library(sf)
```

```
Linking to GEOS 3.11.0, GDAL 3.5.3, PROJ 9.1.0; sf_use_s2() is TRUE
```

```r
library(ggplot2)
```

Download shapes

```r
zip_url = "https://download-v2.suche-postleitzahl.org/wgs84/exakt/plz-5stellig/geojson/plz-5stellig.geojson.zip"
admin_url = "https://daten.gdz.bkg.bund.de/produkte/vg/vg250_ebenen_1231/2019/vg250_12-31.utm32s.shape.ebenen.zip"
fpath_zip = basename(zip_url)
fpath_admin = basename(admin_url)

options(timeout = 600)
download.file(zip_url, fpath_zip)
download.file(admin_url, fpath_admin)

unzip(fpath_zip, exdir = "shapes/zip")
unzip(fpath_admin, exdir = "shapes/admin")
```

```r
zips = st_read("shapes/zip/plz-5stellig.geojson", quiet = TRUE)
municip = st_read("shapes/admin/vg250_12-31.utm32s.shape.ebenen/vg250_ebenen_1231/VG250_GEM.shp", quiet = TRUE)

zips = st_transform(zips, st_crs(municip))
municip = municip[municip$GF == 4L, c("AGS", "GEN")]
names(municip)[1:2] = c('id', 'name')
```

```r
# make map of a zip code with all municipalities intersecting it
make_map = function(zip, ...) {
  z = zips[as.integer(zips$plz) == as.integer(zip), ]
  s2::s2_options(...)
  m = st_intersects(z, municip) |> unlist() |> unique()
  ggplot(municip[m,]) +
  geom_sf(aes(color = name), fill = NA) +
  geom_sf_text(aes(label = name)) +
  geom_sf(aes(geometry = st_centroid(geometry), color = name)) +
  geom_sf(data = z, fill = NA, color = 'red', lwd = 2, lty = 3) +
  theme_void()
}
```

```r
ex_zipcode = 22929
make_map(ex_zipcode) +
  theme(legend.position = "none")
```

[image: ex-zip]

```r
subset(zips, plz == "22929")  |>
st_cast('POLYGON') |>
st_join(municip, join = st_intersects, largest = TRUE)
```

```
Simple feature collection with 4 features and 6 fields
Geometry type: POLYGON
Dimension:     XY
Bounding box:  xmin: 585951.8 ymin: 5933864 xmax: 601251.8 ymax: 5951391
Projected CRS: ETRS89 / UTM zone 32N
         plz                                                   note      qkm
1385   22929 22929 Hamfelde, Kasseburg, Köthel, Rausdorf, Schönberg 38.92175
1385.1 22929 22929 Hamfelde, Kasseburg, Köthel, Rausdorf, Schönberg 38.92175
1385.2 22929 22929 Hamfelde, Kasseburg, Köthel, Rausdorf, Schönberg 38.92175
1385.3 22929 22929 Hamfelde, Kasseburg, Köthel, Rausdorf, Schönberg 38.92175
       einwohner       id      name                       geometry
1385        3720 01062058  Rausdorf POLYGON ((589090.4 5938734,...
1385.1      3720 01053060 Kasseburg POLYGON ((595251.2 5936913,...
1385.2      3720 01053112 Schönberg POLYGON ((594986.6 5951093,...
1385.3      3720 01062040    Köthel POLYGON ((599136.4 5943322,...
```

The goal is to assign the five polygons to the five municipalities given
in the `note`.

How can I match zip codes to municipalities, especially leveraging the
associated municipality information given in `note`? I want to do the
crosswalking for all the (non)unique zip codes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you need a crosswalk table here, in fact it looks to me like you may be on the right track with the spatial join... depending on what exactly you need this data for.

The short answer is, I think, **use [st_intersection](https://r-spatial.github.io/sf/reference/geos_binary_ops.html)**.  You already have your municipal and PLZ polygons, just intersect them to get a single dataset of Ort-PLZ pairs. As I'll discuss in a moment, you will probably end up with many pairs for cities like Hamburg which contain many PLZ's, and some PLZs will match to many towns, but I think this gets you the mapped pairs you're asking for.

**BUT**... I find that a lot of folks asking this question are better off using someone else's geocoder to get ZIP codes into their data.  It all depends on what you want to do.  If you are setting up an application, or you are conducting analysis that needs to be precise, or you're doing anything at all with mail data, or you are setting up a workflow that will be repeated many times in the future... use a geocoder.  Here's why.

So, I hate to bear bad news but I'm afraid this is going to be a little more complicated than you want it to be.  TL,DR: it's not that the codes aren't unique, it's that they:

1. are sometimes *discontinuous* (multipart)
2. are not *actually* polygons, but instead a mixture of points and lines which have been turned into polygons, often poorly, for people who do not understand this
3. frequently change
4. and their "boundaries" don't care about municipal boundaries at all, or really anything beyond the logistics of mail delivery

How you handle these facts depends on what you need to do with the data.  If you're trying to geocode manually, then I *highly* recommend you use a professional geocoder instead, especially if you are setting up a workflow which will be repeated in the future.  If you're just doing a student or personal project, then st_intersect is (probably) perfect.

Postleitzahlen, like US Zip Codes, exist to route mail... *not* to define discreet territorial boundaries.  A common misconception, at least here in the US, is that postal codes each map to some polygonal territory maintained by the postal service.  In fact, each USPS and DP postal code maps to postal delivery *ranges of addresses*... and those ranges change regularly based on the volume of mail sent to/from them.  Most ranges in the US are **one-sided lines** representing a route along one side of a road, usually both sides of a given street fall within a single code but many streets are the dividing line between codes with each side belonging to a different ZIP/PLZ... some PLZs are this way as well and those are what you see polygonized in your data set.  However, in both systems (but more often in Germany) a code may be for a collection of PO Boxes/Postfächer; a single Office/Postamt may have several such collections.  Some codes fall entirely at one location (**a point**), such as the Empire State Building (ZIP 10118) or Humboldt-Universität (PLZ 10099).  **I would be careful that your dataset includes these point PLZs if you need them because a lot of mail passes through them... there are only 8k street address PLZs out of 28k total codes.** The olde paper ["Zip Codes are Not Area Polygons"](http://web.archive.org/web/20050209030255/http://www.manifold.net/cases/zip_codes/zip_codes.html) is a popular resource in this forum on the American flavor of this misconception.

In Germany, the first two PLZ digits describe a Briefzentrum distribution center (the US uses the first three digits FWIW).  The additional digits represent a collection of addresses that the Post (or USPS) may update per changes in staff availability or mail volume between post offices (or of course by opening/closing a location, adding PO boxes etc) and these changes happen constantly.

Thus, the relationship between postal codes and municipal boundaries is fluid, discontinuous and many-to-many: a given town may very well be split between multiple ZIPs/PLZs, and a given code may cover several towns.  It really just comes down to logistics.  There are several multipart Postlietzahlen, like 22929, and ZIP codes too.  Both sets have some rural codes which cross State/Bundesstaat lines.  Some routes may exist where, for example, several routes with shrinking mail volume were combined into a single code. It's a mess, so if you need to handle it professionally I recommend outsourcing the task to Google or whomever has the resources to keep up with PLZ changes; I took a quick look to compare the [Berlin image from suche-postleitzahl](https://www.suche-postleitzahl.org/downloads) with the [data published by DP](https://www.postdirekt.de/plzserver/) and noticed some small differences, of course I don't know the vintage of the image.

So it's not that the code is not unique, its that the code can be multipart (in truth, it's not really a polygon at all).

Comment: Thank you for your detailed and informative answer.